# Is there a way to get $.ajax's default object

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to get all the defaults that are associcate with the `$.ajax` function.

So it would return something like this:

```
{
    global:true,
    headers:{},
    ifModified:false,
    type:"GET",
    url:"the current page url",
    etc....
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From looking at the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js), I believe the (current) defaults are found in `jQuery.ajaxSettings`, of course also available as `$.ajaxSettings`. So if you haven't changed them, you should be able to get them from there.

Note that if you *have* changed them, for example using the `$.ajaxSetup` utility method, you'll get the new defaults you created, not the inherent ones from the jQuery library.

Also looking at the source code, it seems the defaults are the following:

```
ajaxSettings: {
    url: ajaxLocation,
    isLocal: rlocalProtocol.test( ajaxLocParts[ 1 ] ),
    global: true,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    processData: true,
    async: true,
    /*
    timeout: 0,
    data: null,
    dataType: null,
    username: null,
    password: null,
    cache: null,
    traditional: false,
    headers: {},
    */

    accepts: {
        xml: "application/xml, text/xml",
        html: "text/html",
        text: "text/plain",
        json: "application/json, text/javascript",
        "*": "*/*"
    },

    contents: {
        xml: /xml/,
        html: /html/,
        json: /json/
    },

    responseFields: {
        xml: "responseXML",
        text: "responseText"
    },

    // List of data converters
    // 1) key format is "source_type destination_type" (a single space in-between)
    // 2) the catchall symbol "*" can be used for source_type
    converters: {

        // Convert anything to text
        "* text": window.String,

        // Text to html (true = no transformation)
        "text html": true,

        // Evaluate text as a json expression
        "text json": jQuery.parseJSON,

        // Parse text as xml
        "text xml": jQuery.parseXML
    }
},
```

Comment: awesome exactaly what im looking for. Thanks

Comment: @locrizak: Just remember that this is undocumented so it isn't necessarily future proof.

Comment: True, but I would still rather use something in the jquery library rather then rewriting it in another object.

Answer (score 0):

They are listed in the jQuery docs:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: But you can change the defaults using `$.ajaxSetup()`.

Comment: yes but I don't want to hardcode an object because like @mu said `$.ajaxSetup` can overwrite them